# Compare Iso date with current date and convert into desirable Output kotlin

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, datetime

Hey I have Iso Format date. I want to compare with current date. If date is equal to current date, I need the time of given Iso date and otherwise i need date.

```
val date = "2021-10-01T18:39:10.0492422+01:00"
```

How to compare **today’s** date with this value. If date is match i need time in **HH:MM** otherwise **dd MMM YYYY** format.

Important thing my **minSdkVersion 21**

Comment: Vivek - Note that `M` stands for *month* and `m` stands for *minute*; therefore `HH:MM` should be `HH:mm`. Also, `Y` stands for *week-based-year* while you meant `y` which stands for *year-of-era*. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about the symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Java syntax, as I don’t know Kotlin:

```java
LocalDate
.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) )
.isEqual(
    OffsetDateTime
    .parse( "2021-10-01T18:39:10.0492422+01:00" )
    .atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) )
    .toLocalDate()
)
```

As for generating text from *java.time* objects in specific formats using `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` classes, that has been [covered many many times already](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3AStackOverflow.com%20DateTimeFormatter%20java&t=ipad&ia=web). Search to learn more.

## Details

The latest Android tooling brings much of the *java.time* functionality built into Android 26+ to earlier Android via “API de-sugaring”.

In Java syntax…

Parse your input as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2021-10-01T18:39:10.0492422+01:00" ) ;
```

Adjust to the time zone by which you perceive “today’s date”.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Get today’s date as seen in your target time zone, a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Compare to the date of our input as seen in the same time zone.

```
boolean sameDate = today.isEqual( zdt.toLocalDate() ) ;
```

As seen above, you must provide a time zone. **For any given moment, the date varies** around the globe by time zone. Right now is “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US. So to ask “what is the date today?”, you must also specify where, that is, by what time zone do you want to perceive the current date.

Comment: thanks for your help. Can you tell me **ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" )* * is doing and top above example works on api level 21 ?

Comment: (A) For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. Right now is “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US. So to ask “what is the date today?”, you must also specify *where*, that is, by what time zone do you want to perceive the current date. (B) Regarding versions of Android, reread my first sentence in *Details* section.

Comment: can we get system default `zoneid` through `ZoneId.systemDefault()` ? what's the problem if i used this?

Comment: @vivekmodi Yes, you could use the JVM’s current default time zone if appropriate to your needs. But beware: Any code in any thread of any app within a JVM can at any moment change the JVM’s current default time zone thereby affecting immediately all apps within that JVM.

Comment: okk great thanks @BasilBourque.